# Kotlin How to check if there is something to read from the socket?

Tags: android, kotlin, sockets, networking

Kotlin How to check if there is something to read from the socket?
Is there an analog of unix select() in kotlin. As in python select.select(). The application must connect to a python server (I have already done this)
And at the request of the user to send data to the server, and at the request of the server to display some data to the user. How do I check if something was sent from the server side?

Just in case, this is how I send data to the server (it is necessary to receive data through the same socket):

```
private var clientSocket: Socket? = null
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?): Int {
            if (clientSocket != null) {
                var clientSocketOut: OutputStream? = null
                try {
                    clientSocketOut = clientSocket!!.getOutputStream()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace() }
                while (clientSocketOut != null && clientSocket!!.isConnected()) {
                    if (toSend.size > 0){
                        for (nowMsg in toSend){
                            try {
                                clientSocketOut.write((nowMsg.length + 2).toString().toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
                                clientSocketOut.flush()
                                clientSocketOut.write(nowMsg.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
                                clientSocketOut.flush()
                            } catch (e: IOException) {
                                e.printStackTrace()
                            }
                        }
                        toSend.clear()
                    }
                }
            }
```

P.S. unfortunately, the structure and task of the application is such that I do not know at what point the server will need to send something.
unfortunately, the structure and tasks of the application is such that I do not know at what point the server will need to send something. that's why I can't just receive a message from the server after sending it, because it will block the stream.

Comment: When the client sends a command to the server the server should answer. So the client does not need to check. It can just start reading in this scenario.

Comment: unfortunately, the structure and task of the application is such that I do not know at what point the server will need to send something.

Comment: You did not read my comment. A server SHOULD reply every time a client sends a command.

Comment: I'm sorry, I accidentally did not understand the message well. I understood the solution is good and thank you for it, but for me it is unacceptable because I have very limited both performance resources and Internet resources.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found
the InputStream buffer has a .ready() method

```
clientSocket = Socket(SERVER_ADDRESS, SERVER_PORT)
clientSocketIn = clientSocket!!.getInputStream()
var tmp = clientSocketIn!!.bufferedReader(Charsets.UTF_8)
if(tmp.ready()){ ...}
```